# POST request with Java (AsyncTask)

Tags: java, android, curl, android-asynctask

I'm trying make HTTP Post request with Java, here the code

```
protected class DownloadInfoOfWeather extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
        String result = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream write = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            write.writeBytes(params[1]);
            write.flush();
            write.close();

            // Response: 400
            Log.e("Response", connection.getResponseCode() + "");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.toString(), "Something with request");
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public void clickHelloWorld (View view) {

    DownloadInfoOfWeather downloadInfoOfWeather = new DownloadInfoOfWeather();

    String url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
    String body = "q=\"select wind from weather.forecast where woeid=2460286\"&format=json";

    downloadInfoOfWeather.execute(url, body);

}
```

when I run this code, I get Response: 400; 
I use Yahoo API [image]
In other hand with curl everything works fine [image]

Does anyone know how fix this issue?

Comment: set         con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"); too and be sure your String is a json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove quotes from your string it will work just fine - like that

```
.execute(
"https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
"q=select wind from weather.forecast where woeid=2460286&format=json")
```

Also I cleaned up your connection code a little

```
protected static class DownloadInfoOfWeather extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
            writer.write(params[1]);
            writer.close();

            connection.connect();

            // Response: 400
            Log.e("Response", connection.getResponseMessage() + "");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.toString(), "Something with request");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, You got it

Answer (score 0):

it means 1- the web service has problem

2-you send a wrong parameter(your method is post)

and if you want get Strings beter do this :

```
protected class DownloadInfoOfWeather extends AsyncTask<void//notice, Void, String> 
make a counstructor :
DownloadInfoOfWeather(Strings 1 , Strings 2){

}

then : 

new Asyntask(Strings).execute();
//+ this           
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```